# Convert seconds to minutes and seconds in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm working with the youtube API and I'm getting the current time on the video as seconds.
What I want to do is to convert them into this: MM:SS

I've tried to google and try different things by myself but nothing seemed to work and be efficient.

I'll be glad to see how it can be done in a good and efficient way thanks in advance!

Comment: You are telling me that you can not figure out how to divide by 60?

Comment: var timeString:String = ""+Math.floor(youtubetime/60)+":"+youtubetime%60;

Comment: @The_asMan Yea, I got to this, but as I said, I want to get a result of MM:SS, in your solution, it would show: 1:2, I want it to be 01:02, I'm new to this and dont know how to get to that

Comment: sorry @Don but you miss basic programming skills. :(

Comment: @Adrian Pirvulescu True, true. but better to learn later than never :)

Answer (score 6):

Something like:

```
var formattedTime = 
    (Math.floor(seconds/60)) + ":" + // minutes 
    (seconds % 60 >= 10 ? "": "0") + // padding for seconds if needed  
    (seconds % 60));                 // seconds
```

Comment: ((Math.floor(seconds/60)) + ":" + (seconds % 60 >= 10 ? "": "0") + (seconds % 60))

Comment: @emrahgunduz - thanks, indeed `10` was handled wrong in formatting of the time - fixed/added comments.

Answer (score 1):

here is a little class I use all the time just for what you need. I've also added a timecodes to seconds method. Simply use it like `Timecodes.secondsToTimecode(634);` which will output `00:10:34`

```
package com.ronnieswietek.utils
{
    public class Timecodes
    {
        public function Timecodes()
        {
        }

        public static function timecodeToSeconds(tcStr:String):Number
        {
            var t:Array = tcStr.split(":");
            return (t[0] * 3600 + t[1] * 60 + t[2] * 1);
        }

        public static function secondsToTimecode(seconds:Number):String
        {
            var minutes:Number          = Math.floor(seconds/60);
            var remainingSec:Number     = seconds % 60;
            var remainingMinutes:Number = minutes % 60;
            var hours:Number            = Math.floor(minutes/60);
            var floatSeconds:Number     = Math.floor((remainingSec - Math.floor(remainingSec))*100);
            remainingSec                = Math.floor(remainingSec);

            return getTwoDigits(hours) + ":" + getTwoDigits(remainingMinutes) + ":" + getTwoDigits(remainingSec);
        }

        private static function getTwoDigits(number:Number):String
        {
            if (number < 10)
            {
                return "0" + number;
            }
            else
            {
                return number + "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var timeStr:String;
//Video's length >= 1 hour
if( seconds >= 60*60 ){
    //Format-> H:MM:SS
    timeStr = (""+Math.floor(seconds/(60*60))) + //Hours
               ":"+
              ("0"+Math.floor((seconds%(60*60))/60)).substr(-2)+ //Minutes                   
               ":"+
              ("0"+(seconds%60)).substr(-2);         //Seconds
}else{
    //Format-> MM:SS
    timeStr = ("0"+Math.floor(seconds/60)).substr(-2)+ //Minutes
               ":"+
              ("0"+(seconds%60)).substr(-2);         //Seconds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something a little easier to read to get your head around it:

```
var seconds:int = 200;
var minutes:int = 0;

while(seconds >= 60)
{
    seconds -= 60;
    minutes ++;
}

trace(minutes, seconds);
```

The leading zeros part can be done like so:

```
var secStr:String = String(seconds);
var minStr:String = String(minutes);

secStr = (secStr.length == 1) ? "0" + secStr : secStr;
minStr = (minStr.length == 1) ? "0" + minStr : minStr;

trace(minStr + ":" + secStr);
```